# Neo4j Cypher reduce UNWINDs calls

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following Cypher query:

```
UNWIND childD.detailedCriterionIds as dCId
WITH childD, childDStat, dCId + coalesce(childDStat['replaceableCriterionIds.' + dCId],[]) as cGroup
WITH childD, childDStat, cGroup
WHERE NOT AlL(x IN cGroup WHERE x IN $zeroCriterionIds )
WITH childD, childDStat, collect(cGroup) as cGroups
WHERE size(cGroups) >= size(childD.detailedCriterionIds)

WITH childD, childDStat, cGroups
UNWIND cGroups as cGroup
WITH childD, childDStat, cGroup
WHERE ANY(x IN cGroup WHERE x IN $detailedCriterionIds)
WITH childD, childDStat, collect(cGroup) as cGroups
WHERE size(cGroups) > 0
```

As you can see, I use 2 UNWINDs there. Is it possible to optimize this query to avoid the second UNWIND? If so, could you please show how?

I tried the following, but it produced a different result:

```
UNWIND childD.detailedCriterionIds as dCId
WITH childD, childDStat, dCId + coalesce(childDStat['replaceableCriterionIds.' + dCId],[]) as cGroup
WITH childD, childDStat, cGroup
WHERE NOT AlL(x IN cGroup WHERE x IN $zeroCriterionIds )
AND ANY(x IN cGroup WHERE x IN $detailedCriterionIds)
WITH childD, childDStat, collect(cGroup) as cGroups
WHERE size(cGroups) > 0
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: What exactly is "different" in the second result? Also, can you provide sample data and complete queries?

Comment: I think I'm good thanks to your answer below, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second snippet does not have an equivalent to the `size(cGroups) >= size(childD.detailedCriterionIds)` test, so it will not always produce the same result.

In order to do that test, you need to calculate the number of `cGroups`. Therefore, there may not be a better approach than what you are already doing in the first snippet.

*Minor nit: the `WITH childD, childDStat, cGroup` clause is redundant.*

Comment: Thank you! One quick additional question - will Neo4j guarantee that I'll always have `dCId` as `cGroup[0]` ? in the following expression `dCId  + coalesce(childDStat['replaceableCriterionIds.' + dCId],[]) as cGroup` ?

Comment: And one more thing - will the redundant `WITH` affect the overall query performance? Or is this just syntax sugar?

Comment: Use [PROFILE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/query-tuning/query-profile/) to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Hmm. In this expression, `dCId + coalesce(childDStat['replaceableCriterionIds.' + dCId],[])`, `dCid` is used first as a list and then as a scalar. That should not be possible.